# How to give default permissions to a Role for a page when the page is created

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, administration

Is there some configuration where we can provide default Permissions for a Site page for a particular Role?

Similar to the functionality we have in <kbd>Control Panel</kbd> → <kbd>Portal Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Users</kbd>, here we can specify which Roles, Sites or UserGroups can be assigned to the User when the User is created.

To elaborate:

1. I have created a new Role say, `Champion` Role
2. Now I am creating public pages (`Page1`, `Page2` etc) or private pages in a Site, say `Site01`.
3. I require that when the `Page1` was created in `Site01` then the `VIEW` & `UPDATE` permission should be automatically assigned to `Champion` Role.

I know this is possible through a listener hook by having a `LayoutListener` and overriding various methods, but I am looking for another easier or cleaner solution.

Thanks

Comment: Any reason for not just setting a UserGroup and UserRole for all the members of this site ? is the 'Champion Role' used outside of this site ?

Comment: `Champion Role` is a Portal Role, so it could be assigned to any non-member of a Site. So yes it is used outside of this Site. The reason I am asking this is that we are removing permissions from the `Guest` role for everything and would want that some users would not even have VIEW permission for some of the Public pages of some Sites. So in this case we would have a `Champion Role` which would be assigned to some of those Users to have access to the Public Pages of the Sites without being Member of the Site. Let me know if this is not clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could and should do it by using the Liferay's Permission management system, and you should avoid extending code to do your task

Go to <kbd>Control Panel</kbd> → <kbd>Portal</kbd> → <kbd>Roles</kbd> → <kbd>ChampionRole</kbd> → <kbd>Define Permissions</kbd> → <kbd>Sites</kbd>, then
go to the `Site` actions subgroup and check the `VIEW` and `UPDATE`, then use the `Limit Scope` link, where you'll select the site:

[image]

After that, all you have to do is give this role to the right people, e.g like directly applying the Champion Role as a personal role to specific users, by the control panel

Comment: This is a good approach, unfortunately our requirements changed and we now want a way to specify if the `Champion Role` should get only public-page access or private-page access for certain sites. So I guess we would need a listener for that.